# Two node.js applications connected to the same mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have two node.js applications, both of them should connect to the same mongodb database. I should insert document in one application and retrieve it from the other application. I added the same connection of the database to both application. My database is on localhost.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var MONGO_HOSTS = {
  undefined: 'localhost:27017',
  'development': 'localhost:27017',
  'test': 'localhost:27017',
  'staging': process.env.MONGO_HOST,
  'production': process.env.MONGO_HOST
};

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://' + (process.env.MONGO_HOST || MONGO_HOSTS[process.env.NODE_ENV]) + '/test' + process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

Then connect to the database. The problem is that when I insert in one application the other application don't find it. Is this valid way of connection or is there other way.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating via database is not the best pattern. But if you would like to do that, make sure you're trying to read data from DB after write was successful. Try also finding that document using first DB to make sure that your 'find' query is working.